# Viewmodel livedata

Tags: viewmodel, android-livedata

Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0)

not removed
id 'kotlin-android'

Answer (score 0):

Specify both to enforce the latest version for all dependencies:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```